# Python - Continue subprocess.run until text is present in stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess to run a command. I want to quit it when the bash script it runs prints a specific message ("Done"). How can this be done? I think the best way would be to write a wrapper around `sys.stdout`, but I am not sure how this would be done.

```py
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
```

I have also tried a custom command, but when using this, the output becomes laggy, and sometimes does not print

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=2)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
    decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8")
    if "Done!" in decoded_line:
        print(decoded_line)
        process.kill()
        return
    print(decoded_line, end="")
```

Comment: Why not just rewrite the bash script to print "Done" and then `exit 0` ?

Comment: The problem is that the bash script uses "tail -f", and thus will not be able to exit